# Find specific div on click and toggle class

Tags: javascript, jquery, coffeescript, haml

Here's my current markup:

```
      .image_container{style: 'background-image: url(' + item['image'] + ')'}

      [...]

        .product_images_link{data: {id: item["objectId"]}}

      %form.product_info{action: "post", id: "item_#{item['objectId']}"}
        %h3.title= item['name']
        %a.remove
```

I have a CoffeeScript function that toggles class ".add" on a.remove. I want click this link to also toggle a class of "unselected" to ".image_container".

My current function looks like this:

```
 toggleProduct: (evt) ->
   button = $(evt.currentTarget)
   button.toggleClass 'add'
   $(evt.currentTarget).find('.image_container').toggleClass 'unselected'
```

How do I find and toggle the class on .image_container?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is `.image_container` a child of the button? If so, your code should work. Here's a variation of what I think you're trying to achieve:

http://jsfiddle.net/nhahV/

If it's not inside the button, you just need to use a different jQuery search to find it:

http://jsfiddle.net/nhahV/1/

As you can see, I'm using `$button.parent().find('img')`.

You can also assign it an id, and toggle it based on some property that that button has:

http://jsfiddle.net/nhahV/2/

I added a `data-toggle` attribute to the button with a value of the id of whatever you want to toggle, and using `$('#' + $button.attr('data-toggle'))` selector to search for the element.

Comment: As shown in my current markup, .image_container is a parent of the button, I think that's my issue but I'm not sure how to select it.

Comment: @mtthwbsh I added some other examples in the answer to show how to reference elements outside the button.